# Problem loading fonts ASP.NET Core Hosting

Tags: asp.net-core, web, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm starting to host a Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC Web Site (accessible from http://www.ingeco.cu).
The big issue is that I'm using static fonts and they aren't loading, and neither the favicon. In the development process it works perfectly the issue comes when I run it in the hosting.

I'm hosting it in a Proxmox Container with Debian 10, using Nginx as reverse proxy.
What I should do so the fonts can be loaded correctly?

Comment: How do you add custom font to your project ?

Comment: With using the main css file of the site. Example: @font-face {
    font-family: 'kozgopr6n-regular';
    src: url('../fonts/kozukagothicpr6n/kozgopr6n-regular.otf') format('opentype');
}

Comment: Did you check the permission of font file ? try chmod 777 on it and test again.

Comment: The thing is when I run it in Visual Studio it works perfectly, even if I run it in my windows pc it works fine, the thing is when is running in the hosting container.

Comment: Yes all the files have the rights established to 777

Comment: check the console of your browser. Did you get 404 not found on your font path ?

Comment: yes, an 404 error

Comment: You should be able to get access to font when directly enter the address of font file on your browser. If not permission or incorrect path address is your problem. Note in linux containers, it is important to check your URL for case sensitiveness.

Comment: THAT'S IT! Yeah, the big issue, the case sensitiveness. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. please mark answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get access to font when directly enter the address of font file on your browser. If not incorrect permission or incorrect path address is your problem. Note in linux containers, it is important to `check your URL for case sensitiveness.`

Comment: The big issue was that in Linux the case sensitiveness important, and I didn't check that the directory containing the font family started with a capital letter, I've changed it and ready. The web site is accessible at http://www.ingeco.cu, is in development yet.